# Video View android Studio

Tags: android

I want to develop a media player with VideoView in Android Studio. I create a folder, called raw, whose contents are the video that I want to display on the video view. But the program give me a warning in raw when I write R.raw.nameofvideo (in this case "cloud").

Can anyone see where the problem is?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button play;
    Button pause;
    Button reset;
    VideoView video;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


    }

    public void onClickStart(View view)
    {
        String videoPath = "android.resource://com.example.andrea.video/"+R.raw.cloud;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the raw resource ID as if it was the actual value. When you are using `R.raw.your_resource` you are not calling the resource but only its internal ID.

If you want to load a raw resource, you need to call `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_resource)` and that will give you a `InputStream` you can read from.

Your example is misleading, it seems you just want to use your resource as a part of the URL. In that case, it would be even simplier for you to store it as a `values/strings.xml` resource and get it as `getResources().getString(R.string.mystring)`.